# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3 missing UWP and UAP projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, uap

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3 with Windows 10 SDK.

[image]

All SDK are installed fine but I can't create UWP or UAP project because Visual Studio has not these templates.

[image]

I reinstalled and restored visuals studio many times. I installed Windows 10 SDK and Emulator from seperately setup file. But I can't see UWP or UAP templates in Visual Studio.

Visual Studio doesn't see Windows 10 SDK in About window.

[image]

Help me please.

Comment: You are not alone - same troubles with UWP applications on Lenovo MIIX with Win10 1607 32bit. On all other PCs no problems (all 64bit). May be clue in platform?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely install Visual Studio 2017, because in VS 2015 you cannot target on Creator update of Windows 10 SDK or higher, which could be the source of your problem.

Answer (score -1):

UWP Template install only via online. You have tried with Online ? , If not please enable internet and try , it should work.